# Demand Forecasting methods for hundreds of time series

Tags: machine-learning, regression, data-science-model, forecasting

I have TFL cycling [dataset](https://cycling.data.tfl.gov.uk/usage-stats/369JourneyDataExtract08May2023-14May2023.csv) for the time period from JAN 2023 to JUNE 2023. I would like to forecast the demand or expected no. of trips for each station at every hour of the day.

Post some data processing, below are my predictor variables -

Start station number
Bike model
start_hour
start_day_of_week
start_month
trip_duration_bins

I would essentially be predicting the likely number of journeys for each station at every hour of the day each day that fall into <30 min, 30-60 min and more than 1hr trip duration categories.

1. I'm not clear if I can just use a linear regression, tree based regression method etc. or if I must use time series methods alone.
2. If I can use any regression method, can I shuffle split data into training and validation or does it have to be time-series split?
3. If I must use a time series method (which I don't have much knowledge of), how do I go about it? I'm confused because it feels like no. of journeys at each station over time would be a time series and we have 100s of time series as there are many stations.
4. If it is the case that each station's trips every hour is a time series, then how to do things like removing seasonality for 100s of time series and find model order for them?

Probably stupid questions because I'm new to this stuff. But, thanks in advance.